# Trying to get Button on Dialog Box for post comment

Tags: android, android-layout

I Want to send button similar to Instagram Comment Section. But when i run the application only Textfield Appear.

Here is My XML

**Popup.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg"
    android:padding="10px">
//Receive the comment from Api
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/popup_rcv">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/new_comment_et"
            android:hint="Please enter Comment"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/comment_btn"
            android:text="Submit"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I Want to send button similar to Instagram Comment Section. But when i run the application only Textfield Appear.

Because your `EditText` width is `match_parent` just add some weight in your 
`EditText`

Just add **`android:layout_weight="1"`** in your **`EditText`**

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg"
    android:padding="10px">
//Receive the comment from Api
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/popup_rcv">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/new_comment_et"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Please enter Comment"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/comment_btn"
            android:text="Submit"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: One should use `android:layout_width="0dp"` along with weight in the `Editext` for better performance.

Comment: @ankuranurag2 agree with u buddy

Comment: Hi sir, can you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54685955/onactivityresult-not-getting-called-in-fragment-where-intent-pass-from-adapter-c